# Facebook group posts are now organized by 'top posts' rather than 'most recent', why?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I am a member of many yard sale groups in my area. It used to be that the posts were listed by recent activity. Now they are listed by 'top posts', which are often much older than the new posts. For instance, someone posted a sale 1 minute ago, but it is buried under numerous posts from days ago, even though *no one bumped* those posts.

I understand the use of this feature for the newsfeed but why is Facebook doing this in groups? Is there a way to change it?

Comment: This setting seems to change at-will in all areas of Facebook. Good Luck trying to make it stick.